# Show that Sx is an eigenvector of this matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$D^TSD=S$  (eqn 1), where $S$ isn't degenerate. Let $\mu$ be an eigenvalue of $D$, with eigenvector **x**. Show that $S$**x** is an eigenvector of $D^T$ and find its eigenvalue.

I've got this far: $D^TS$**x** = $\lambda S$**x**. Sub this into (1):
$\lambda S$**x**$SD$ = $S$. Then I could pre-multiply by $S^-1$ to get 
$\lambda$**x**$SD = I.
$

Multiplying by **x** in (1) gives $S$**x** = $D^TSD$**x**.

And now I don't think this is really going anywhere! Completely wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $D^{T}SD = S$, let $\mathbf{x}$ be an eigenvector of $D$ (so $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$) with corresponding eigenvalue $\mu$. Then you can write
$$
S\mathbf{x} = D^{T}SD\mathbf{x} = \mu D^{T}S\mathbf{x}.
$$
Since $S\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$ by assumption, then $\mu\neq0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so... does that make the eigenvalue $\frac{1}{\mu}$?

Comment: Yeah, that will be the eigenvalue of $D^{T}$ corresponding to $S\mathbf{x}$.